# Bounds on eigenfunctions of integraloperator

Tags: real-analysis, compact-operators, eigenfunctions

Let $K: [0,1]\times[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a symmetric positive definit and continuous function.
It is known my Mercer's theorem that 
$$ [T_K \varphi](x) =\int_0^1  K(x,s) \varphi(s)\, ds $$
is compact and can be written as
$$ K(s,t) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \lambda_j \, e_j(s) \, e_j(t), $$
where $(e_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2([0,1])$.

My question is: What can be said about the uniform norm of the $e_i$, i.e. I am looking for a bound of the form
$$
\|e_i\|_{L_\infty(0,1)} \leq C(\lambda_i).
$$

Is there anything in this direction known? Thanks!

Comment: the integral should go from 0 to 1, shouldnt it.

Comment: for continuous $\varphi$, because $K$ is continuous, the operator $T$ can be defined as the limit of a sequence of matrices $T_N : N \times N$ acting on $\varphi(n/N)_{n \in \{0 \ldots N-1\}}$